# How to modify a return json

Tags: json, api, go

I'm taking the data from the `github API` with `golang`, however, I want to send to the front only the necessary data (`id`, `name`, `url`, `language` and `description`) instead of just returning everything that the `github API` gives me.

```
func GetAllReposStars(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    enableCors(&w)
    params := mux.Vars(r)
    username := params["username"]

    res, err := http.Get("https://api.github.com/users/" + username + "/starred")

    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body)
    res.Body.Close()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    log.Printf("Body: %s\n", body)

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    w.Write(body)
    json.NewEncoder(w)
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can define a type that has only the keys you need and decode the response from the GitHub API into a variable of that type so that only the keys you need are kept, then write that variable to the response.

For example:

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "log"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
)

type RelevantRepoData struct {
    Id          int    `json:"id"`
    Name        string `json:"name"`
    Url         string `json:"url"`
    Language    string `json:"language"`
    Description string `json:"description"`
}

func GetAllReposStars(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    enableCors(&w)
    params := mux.Vars(r)
    username := params["username"]

    res, err := http.Get("https://api.github.com/users/" + username + "/starred")

    var repoData RelevantRepoData
    err = json.NewDecoder(res.Body).Decode(&repoData)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(repoData)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to send some specific fields to front-end but in future want to handle them on backend, you can use `json:"-"` in your struct

e.g :

```
type RelevantRepoData struct {
    Irrelevant  string `json:"-"`
    Id          int    `json:"id"`
    Name        string `json:"name"`
    Url         string `json:"url"`
    Language    string `json:"language"`
    Description string `json:"description"`
}
```

When you return this object, the fields with `json:"-"` will be ignored but you can still use them on backend.